# Vercel deployment error : BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1 & Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: next.js, vercel, vercel-micro

I'm facing this:

> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
>
> Deployment completed
>
> BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I also tried, by setting environment variable  CI to false. It would look like this:

`CI = false`

What to do now?

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: For me I ran `npm build` locally (in VS -Code)to find what was the root cause of the issue.I  found it was an export issue fixed it and it worked.